# Temporary "emergency" electrical power supply improvisation

Tags: electrical

Someone fraudulently terminated my contract with my local utility so they disconnected my house without my consent (also the grid operator's notice never reached the people living there and paying for energy, because the adversary also has post diverted).
The disconnect happened two days ago, which is against the law (not before weekends and public holidays). Emergency stand-by refuses to help because for them it is a contract issue, not a failure.

A kind neighbor plugged a single-phase, 230 VAC extension cord into a receptacle on the outside of their house, so I could charge my mobile and get rid of the candles at least.

I am in Lower Austria. We have three-phase 400 VAC supply to the main panel where circuits go off 1-N or 2-N or 3-N alternating to get the standard 230V for room outlets and light.

Their cable is on 16A fuse. Can I switch my main three-phase+N breaker to the off position, connect the three phases, and connect the live of the extension cord to that, and the common N to the extension cord's N, and both PEs to get a safe, temporary, emergency supply to my house, when I take care to switch on only a bare minimum of light/appliances at the same time?

Comment: Not a smart idea to jury rig 400 volts. Plus, they could charge you with current diversion.  If they received an order for disconnect they can do it immediately.  The weekend/holiday rule only applies to disconnect for non payment. Any clue as to who did this to you?

Comment: entirely different story, handed over to my lawyers already. when the neighbor agrees, is it still diversion? also, its no more than 24 hours from now. they're expected to reconnect monday morning. I'm considering rigging 3 x 230V, oven and machinery circuits off, just outlets and light.

Comment: I could as well connect just one of the phases, but then some rooms would work and some not, better than nothing though.

Comment: If neighbor agrees, you're ok.....  and use the extension cord properly... don't be cutting and connecting.  that voltage can kill you.

Comment: Can you get another extension cord and chop it in half?  Also, are you OK with just powering up one circuit, or do you need all of them powered?

Comment: affirmative. one is sufficient, as the kids' rooms and mine are on the same leg. more would be convenient but I could do with just one.

Comment: With your main off I have done similar on this side of the pond your voltage is higher but current is lower. I would try to keep the load to a minimum just for safety, at your higher voltage , voltage drop may not be a question but cord ends may overheat. Over here I have seen 24 amp heaters on 30 amp molded plugs melt down the pug was rated for 30 amps , so I would keep an eye on the plug even if not at the maximum load.

Comment: if you don't have the correct transfer switch setup, such a jury rig could hinder them from reconnecting your electricity service

Comment: @Jasen -- a "temporary inlet/cord" setup as Harper describes won't be an issue from the PoCo's standpoint (as it does not require procedural controls to avoid backfeeding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You cannot rely on procedures to avoid backfeeding

So it is not enough to switch off the main breaker and then tie a string on your finger to remind you not to turn it on.  You must actually remove the meter, or output wires from the house side of the main breaker (many European panels have wires run between main and branch circuit breakers). The panel must be rendered safe from someone turning on the main breaker or any other breaker unawares, and backfeeding must be impossible.

### My usual approach is to rewire the panel "permanently", then rewire it back

The hot and neutral from the various circuits can be attached to an **inlet** or if your Code allows, a short electric cord with a proper strain relief and fittings leaving the panel.

Internal to the panel, you jumper it around so any circuits which need power are pulling hot and neutral pull from the inlet/cord.  Do all this properly, using permanent wiring methods to Code.

Then, when power returns, you put it back the way it originally was.

You must be careful not to "paint yourself into a corner", i.e. don't disconnect anything that will be energized when power returns.  In fact, while working, assume the power company could restore power *at any moment*.

Comment: the power is probably back on by now.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar from instinct: as the meter and supply-side of the main breaker are under sealed covers, I disconnected all four wires from the accessible side of the main breaker, insulated them individually, and wired the inlet to common N, PE, and the one of the three primary circuits - before the secondary circuit breakers - that gave me the best coverage of rooms. lighting in unpowered rooms simply by extension cords and household lamps. Now power is back and I live to tell the tale. This is sound advice. Yet something one shouldn't ever need to consider.